# Axios get html and a href change to localhost instead of original path

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, href

I strungle with this, in resume I'm using axios to get a directory content of a remote server in other network. The path of the directory in that server is :
[image]

my front response.data is like this:
[image]

I'm using a div and

```
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = response.data;
```

inside the .get function to load all the html included de 'a' tags but href changed.

Now is like this:
[image]

so the problem is that it changed the href from 192.168.110.83:8080/signed/ to localhost:8080/

how can i maintain the original href?? or is it imposible to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can manage original href like:

```js
const htmlContent = response.data.replace(/http:\/\/192\.168\.110\.83:8080\/signed\//g, '/signed/');
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = htmlContent;
```

Comment: Hi Mitesh, I tried to run your answer but it didn`t change the href, it shows as mention before the localhost:8080 not http://192.168.110.83:8080/signed/

Comment: i manage to do it with: const htmlContent = response.data.replace(/href=\"/g, 'href="http://192.168.110.83:8080/signed/'); your answer actually helped me so thank you i mark it as resolve

Comment: @EduardoNicolalde yeah, wlcm :)